# Cells data Wrapping in Html or css or Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to display a sentence "some of the transaction processed successfully" but the td size is less to accommodate this. So its height is changing. I don't want to use nowrap also since it changes the width. I need to Display some thing like this "Some of the transaction...." how to achieve this.? any CSS or script 'll help me.. thanks in advance.

```
Current Status: Some of the transaction processed successfully
Expected: Some of the transaction....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-overflow: ellipsis` with `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap` and fixed width in pixels.

Restrict by width.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<div>Some of the transaction processed successfully</div>
```

---

Using Javascript `substring`.

Restrict by number of characters.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('message'),
  message = div.innerHTML.trim();

div.innerHTML = message.length > 20 ? message.substr(0, 20) + '...' : message;
```

```html
<div id="message">Some of the transaction processed successfully</div>
```

For table elements, you need to add `div` inside `td`. Check [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/t3m7c7r8/).

Comment: Thanks its working.But still.... can we do this without div element since i have performed some operation on td data i dont want to make it with div.

Comment: @GaneshNB Yes, that can be done, I've used `div` just for the demo purpose

Comment: @GaneshNB Can you create jsfiddle demo

Comment: i have created JSfiddle as a seperate answer above

Comment: @GaneshNB Check this https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/t3m7c7r8/, you need to add `div` inside the `td`

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS [`text-overflow: ellipsis;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp):

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;      

  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Adds dots in the end on overflow */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Disallows line break */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hides overflowing text */
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv" style="width: 100px;">
  Very long text very long text very long text
</div>
<div class="myDiv" style="width: 200px;">
  Very long text very long text very long text
</div>
<div class="myDiv" style="width: 500px;">
  Very long text very long text very long text
</div>
```